# Clausius inequality and negative value of entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I was wondering...if entropy is a "state function" then why does going through an irreversible cycle give a negative value for entropy (Clausius inequality), I know it might be due to the fact that entropy is an unnatural transformation but I want to understand why? cause it is still a cycle... why it isn't a zero value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering...if entropy is a "state function" then why does going
> through an irreversible cycle give a negative value for entropy
> (Clausius inequality),

The Clausius inequality is not the change in entropy of the heat engine over a cycle, which of course must be zero. The Clausius inequality states that for an irreversible cycle the entropy given to the surroundings during the cycle is larger than the entropy transferred to the engine by heat from the hot reservoir in the surroundings.

In order for the total change in entropy of any heat engine cycle to be zero over the cycle, any entropy transferred to the heat engine from the surroundings, $S_{IN}$, plus any entropy generated in the heat engine due to irreversible processes,$S_{GEN}$, must be transferred to the environment, $S_{OUT}$, or

$S_{IN} + S_{GEN} = S_{OUT}$

Since, for an irreversible cycle, over the cycle more entropy is leaving the heat engine ($S_{IN} + S_{GEN}$), than transferred into the heat engine ($S_{IN}$),by an amount equal to the entropy generated in the cycle ($S_{GEN}$) we obtain

$$\oint_{engine} \frac{\delta Q}{T}\lt 0$$

For a more complete discussion see:

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/clausius.html#c1

Hope this helps.